# Is ClearCase supported in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2010, plugins, clearcase

I'm looking for information about support for using ClearCase in Visual Studio 2010, I'm writing up an evaluation of VS 2010 and need some info on SCS other than TFS and SVN and was wondering if there is a plugin being developed for ClearCase and VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always seen Rational IBM integration support *after* the release of the product (eclipse, Visual Studio, ...)

And VS2010 won't be release before the [22nd of March 2010](http://www.ithinkdiff.com/microsoft-sets-22nd-march-as-the-release-date-for-visual-studio-2010/)

A plugin should then be proposed by Rational (for the CC client and the CCRC remote client)

---

The "Marketing Communications Manager for Developer and User Experience Runtimes and Tools at Microsoft"  [Rob CARON just said](http://blogs.msdn.com/robcaron/archive/2010/01/13/9948172.aspx) (January 13th)

> Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4 will launch on **Monday, 12 April 2010**.

Comment: Actually, the launch date will be even later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440156/when-is-net-4-0-and-visual-studio-2010-supposed-to-be-released

Answer (score 3):

ClearCase 7.1.1 update for Visual Studio 2010 is available for download.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24024532

Answer (score 1):

IBM Rational has announced that ClearCase support for Visual Studio 2010 is slated for Q2 2010.