# Re-integrating Clearcase with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clearcase

I've seen the questions on ClearCase [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063979/is-clearcase-supported-in-visual-studio-2010) and [integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952808/clearcase-integration-with-visual-studio), but both didn't help. Seen [this](http://greghurlman.com/2010/10/27/friends-dont-let-friends-use-clearcase/) too, but well...

I had a VS2010 project with which I was able to check in and out files within VS itself, but sometime back, it showed that it couldn't connect to ClearCase, and now I when I right click on the project files in solution explorer, the ClearCase options aren't even available in the right-click menu.

How do I get it to work with ClearCase now?
I'm able to check in and out the files from Windows explorer and from ClearCase explorer, but how to do it through Visual Studio?
(Note: The 'ClearCase' option in `Tools>Options>SourceControl` is already selected)

Comment: What exact error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rare case I have seen that were:

- incompatibility with a VM64bits (I believe this is now solve)
- due to a ClearCase update (only solution was to uninstall ClearCase, uninstall VS2010, reinstall VS2010 first, then ClearCase)

Note that [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21421687) (originally about CCRC, which isn't your case) does mention

> **ClearCase** and CCRC versions **7.0.1 and 7.1.1**
>
> There is no Visual Studio 2010 integration available during an installation of ClearCase or CCRC versions 7.0.1.x or 7.1.1 or 7.1.1.1.
>   Refer to the workaround details below for information about obtaining a utility and for instructions for setting up the integration.
>
> WORKAROUND
>
> A utility is available along with instructions on setting up the integration. If you have any questions or issues with using this utility, contact IBM Rational Client Support for assistance.

Refer to [document 4024532](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21438664) Integrate ClearCase and CCRC 7.0.1 and 7.1.1 with Visual Studio 2010 for details.

So it depends also about your exact ClearCase version.

The aforementioned technote (4024532) refers to:

> When using the ClearCase integration with Visual Studio 2010, glyphs indicating the source control state for ASP.Net Web Site projects are not displayed in Solution Explorer.

(Meaning it can also depends about the *type* of your VS project)

> The defect with Microsoft WebSite project has been fixed in Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
>   Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is supported from ClearCase 7.1.1.6 and 7.1.2.3 onwards.

(Meaning it also depends about the exact version of your VS itself)

Your case doesn't seem to refer to that issue, since you don't even have ClearCase contextual menu on the project files of your solution (hence my advice to uninstall everything and re-install), but illustrates the need to know the exact details about:

- the error message
- the version of ClearCase
- the version of VS2010

Comment: I forgot what the error was (*I just remember trying to create a new project, where during creation it gives the option of add to source control, and although that was selected, it could not connect to clearcase and asked me if I'd like to remove all clearcase bindings for that project. I said yes, but I don't understand why clearcase disappeared for my older projects which had the clearcase context menu and functionality working perfectly*), but clearcase version is 7.0.1.0. Visual studio version of .NET framework 4.0.30319 RTMRel.

Comment: @Nav: can you reproduce the issue with *another* project already versioned in ClearCase that you would import to VS2010?

Comment: Nope. Can't reproduce it. I have a bunch of projects that are versioned in ClearCase, but now when I open any of them, they no longer show the clearcase menu options in the right-click menu. (*p.s: thanks for being there to help out*)

Comment: @Nav: ok, that would be consistent with the "remove all clearcase bindings" dialog. So uninstalling CC et VS2010, and re-installing first VS2010, then CC should help.

Comment: \*groan\*! Re-installing is a bit of a pain :) Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Nav: I feel your pain (been there many times). The other option is try to look in the registry (by comparing it with another one from another workstation where the integration CC-VS is still in place) and see if you can restore the right parameter within your registry.

Comment: The root folder of one such project file was added to source control but the files inside it weren't because of the error. I right clicked on the solution in solution explorer and selected add to source control. I got an error saying that it couldn't add a .vcxproj to source control PFM_ASSERT:(cl_rec==cl_rec_root&&cl_rec->magic==MAGIC_SET) failed:'..pfm.c":562ccccdeadError. But after the error, I saw that other files had actually got added to source control. Weird. Faced timeout issues yesterday, but today it seems slow but ok. Will post if I make any more headway. Everything seems ok for now